# How can I test my NGINX website without a domain name?

Tags: webserver, nginx, static-ip, cloud

I configured 3 server blocks on nginx for 3 different domain names. But I’m yet to buy domain names. If I enter server IP address like http://53.208.12.57/index.html it was only opening first website (/var/www/site1/index.html). How to see my 2nd & 3rd websites on (/var/www/site2/index.html and /var/www/site3/index.html)?

I also tried opening http://53.208.12.57/site2/index.html also, but it was not working. So what is the correct path to open 2nd website?

Comment: You can add them to your host files and use dummy domain names. Or you can point nginx to `/var/www/` so you can use `http://1.1.1.1/site2/index.html` or `http://1.1.1.1/site3/index.html`.

Comment: The former may work better in some situations. OP needs to add an OS so you can post a more complete answer. What os *is* this on? ;p

Comment: Don't invent fake IPs in any case. You never need to hide private RFC1918 IPs (like 192.168.x.x), leave them as is; you want to replace your public IPs, you have to either replace them with private ones or with IPs from TEST-NET-x defined in [RFC5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735) (for example, 192.0.2.x). The use of "53.208.12.57" in the question is valid only if you really have that IP, and use of "1.1.1.1" in the comment above is absolutely invalid, don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the IP address does not match any `server_name` in your configuration, so `nginx` will use the default server.

You can manually add the IP address to one of your sites for the purposes of testing that site, or add the keyword `default_server` to its `listen` directive to move the default server away from the first `server` block.

For example:

```
server_name site2.example.com 53.208.12.57;
```

Or:

```
listen 80 default_server;
```

I realise that this is not ideal, as you will need to restart `nginx` to test each website. You can specify the Host header with `curl`, but I do not think that is the kind of test you are interested in performing.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for details.